# Handling Large Datasets with Blank Rows in every column in R

Tags: r

##### Background

I am currently working with a very large dataset in R. I exported this data from Google Cloud using the bigquery bucket option, and all the datasets were exported into the bucket I had created, in CSV format. Afterward, I downloaded all the files to my desktop and imported one of them into R for a preview before performing any cleaning.

##### Problem

When I attempted to use the head function in R to preview the first 6 rows, it displayed "NA" throughout. This issue persisted when I utilized the str and glimpse functions. When I opened the same file in Excel, I discovered that the reason for the "NA" values was because over 10,000 rows in each column were entirely blank. Unfortunately, Excel was ineffective for handling this large dataset and caused my laptop to hang, preventing the operation from completing.

##### Objective

My objective is to eliminate all the blank rows in every column then repeat this process for the remaining data after which I can merge all the datasets into one dataset prior to the cleaning process. Please note that there are 16 columns in the dataset, and the first 10,000 rows in each column are empty.

Thank you.

Comment: You might have a look at `janitor::remove_empty` which will drop all rows containing only missings.

Comment: hi Ademola! Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried `readr::read_csv("example.csv", col_names = TRUE, skip = 10000)`

Comment: Hello Stefan,

Thank you for your contribution. Could you please guide me on how to use the remove::janitor option? I have already loaded the data into a data frame named df_trips_01.

Comment: Hello Mark,

I attempted the approach using the dataframe name I assigned to the data, readr::read_csv("df_trips_01", col_names = TRUE, skip = 10000)and it was successful. However, when I tried to view the data, I encountered an error: "Error in View: object 'df_trips_01.csv' not found."

I'm wondering if there's a way to remove all the blank rows present in the data without specifying a fixed number of rows. The initial estimate of 10,000 blank rows was just an approximation; there are actually more than 10,000 blank rows.

I appreciate your guidance on these matters.

Thank you.

Comment: in that case, you want to use @stefan's approach. Keep in mind that that is likely to be a decent amount slower than mine for very large datasets

Comment: Try `df_trips_01 <- janitor::remove_empty(df_trips_01)`.

Comment: I reloaded the dataset and placed it in a new dataframe. When I utilized the "view" function, it worked correctly. Here's the code I used for this process:

**df_cleaned_citytrips01 <- readr::read_csv("/Users/ADEMOLA/biketrips/citybike_trips30.csv", col_names = TRUE, skip = 98717)**


The value "98717" corresponds to the number of blank rows in the data. I had to manually scroll through to ascertain where the blank rows concluded. I sincerely appreciate all of your assistance. This holds significant value for me.